# how can I update an element id value to be value+text?

Tags: jquery

I would like to set all the children IDs of a div to their ID + a number. Here is an example of code that doesn't work, but it should give an idea of what I want it to do.

For each child, I want to change the ID attribute to be the ID + inputs_count.

I am doing this because I cloned a div with some children and I want to append the clone count onto each child div id to maintain uniqueness.

```
$(parentDiv).children().attr('id', this.attr('id')+inputs_count);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this without a loop by providing a function to the `attr()` method which updates the current value of the attribute in each element of the set. Try this:

```
$(parentDiv).children().attr('id', function(i, v) {
    return v + i;
});
```

In the anonymous function `i` is an integer containing an interator, and `v` is the current value of the attribute.

http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-function

Comment: This is excellent, but I had to use the other answer because I need the appended number to be the same for each. LIke div_a_1 div_b_1 div_c_1 and so on. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I got to work this morning and realized your code works, I just omitted the iterator and used my own counter.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
$(parentDiv).children().each(function()
{
  $(this).attr('id', $(this).attr('id')+inputs_count);
});
```

Example : http://jsfiddle.net/nkgtf278/1/